# Extremely high bandwidth usage for OCSP?

Tags: ocsp

ISPs where I live charge based on usage. A friend just moved here and blew through 60 GB of data ($115) in a couple weeks. When asked, the ISP provided a .csv of URLs and bandwidth usage over those 2 weeks. A pivot of that data shows extremely high usage at a couple of OCSP URLs (apple, digicert, sectigo) as shown in image below.

[image: Bandwidth Usage by URL table]

The household has 1 Windows 10 PC, 1 iPhone, 1 Samsung Android, 1 Wiko Smart Phone (android), 3 newish iPads. 3 adults 3 small kids.

*Does this seem legit* (does it pass the laugh test):

- Is ~190 KB the expected average size of an OCSP response?
- Does the size of the response suggest anything about its nature?
- Is it reasonable that 4 iDevices would make a total of ~2,500 OCSP requests per day to ocsp.apple.com?
- Would those be requests for app certificate validity, or do all SSL certs visited in Safari get checked at ocsp.apple.com?

*Any ideas as to what could be causing it?* I guess I'm really asking if there's anything here that raises red flags for malware, virus, compromised router, etc.

Comment: Many OCSP requests = many certs to check = probably someone browsing without adblock, possibly even click fraud apps. Take the devices one by one and spy on their network activity like your ISP is spying on you (what!)

Comment: **60 GB for $115** - What the actual f...?

Comment: The timeframe is two weeks. $800 will get you 1TB valid up to 6 months - a much better deal than the 75GB/2month package.

Comment: is the ISP providing those domain names? I would want to see IP addresses, because RDNS is easily forged.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this seem legit?

It is impossible to know just from bandwidth numbers. It's like asking "is this charge on my credit card legit?" - it depends on if you made the purchase.

> Any ideas as to what could be causing it?

You have a basic network troubleshooting scenario here. Set up packet captures within the network or logging on the router and see what is making the requests, then you can narrow down which devices are making the requests.

Comment: Edited question for clarity - agree that isolating devices will provide a better picture. My colleagues lack the skills to do that, and I'd like to get a sense of whether this passes the laugh test or if we should be concerned about this data as a marker for something malicious.

Comment: The short answer is "no", this is not normal at all. And it requires further investigation before any malicious intent can be determined or to know what is causing it. Unfortunately, only packet captures or router logs will do this.